# Does the android application that registered a BroadcastReceiver receive a broadcast if it is no running?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I have `android` application that registered a `BroadcastReceiver`, can the application receive the broadcast if the application is not running in the time the broadcast is triggered ?

If NO, how can I make it receive broadcasts when the application is not running ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can the application receive the broadcast if the application is not running in the time the broadcast is triggered ?

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via a `<receiver>` element in the manifest, then yes.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via `registerReceiver()`, called on some `Context`, then no.